Unexpected behavior with custom transparency of raster in QGIS 3.24.3

I have noticed an unexpected behavior while playing with custom transparency of a single band raster (Digital elevation model; .flt format).
I mistype the transparency value I wanted  and made it 500% (instead of 50%). When I  applied, I obtained the following result:
FYI, here is what it looks like without transparency:

I am very curious to know what happen behind the scene here.

Well, it's kinda handy, I found out while giving a look at some geophysical map, and it behave kind of like edge enhancer for bodies wavelength decreasing with opacity (/with increasing transparency)
